# Word Selection.InsertColumns "ломает" таблицу, а ручное добавление - нет

Tags: vba, ms-word

мне нужен макрос, который будет добавлять в каждую таблицу столбец (на самом деле, он делает больше, но проблема именно со вставкой). Я использую Selection.InsertColumns. Это работает с простыми таблицами, но возникает проблема с таблицами, где есть объединенные ячейки - если попытаться вставить макросом столбец ПЕРЕД столбцом с объединенными ячейками, то колонки таблицы начинают "ехать". НО при этом, если вставить туда же столбец слева вручную (без макроса), то все ок. Никак не могу понять, в чем дело... В примере, если выделить первый столбец (по сути, два столбца с одним заголовком) и вставить колонки слева вручную, то все ок, а если вставить их макросом, то таблица ломается.
[image: пример]

Comment: Приветствие почему-то обрезалось)

Comment: Запишите "процесс вручную" макрорекордером и сравните со своим кодом.

Comment: Изначально так и сделал - он добавил строку Selection.InsertColumns, которой я пользуюсь.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что тот код, который Вы записали при ручной беспроблемной вставке, при запуске записанного макроса ломает форматирование? И записывать надо весь процесс: выделение источника - копирование - выделение приёмника - вставку.

Comment: Попробовал полностью записать и получил код:Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdColumn, Extend:=True;    Selection.InsertColumns. Этот код все равно ломает таблицу) а сам я пользуюсь для выделения столбца следующим кодом (тоже ломает таблицу): Set Cll = Tbl.Cell(1, colNum); Cll.Select; Selection.SelectColumn; Selection.InsertColumns